# How to get the one side pady/padx of a tkinter widget?

Tags: python, tkinter

I am trying to iterate through the tkinter widgets of a script and extract their pady up and down values (the ones assigned with `widget_ex.grid(pady=(pad_up,pad_down))`).

From `widget_ex.grid(pady=(0,20),sticky="w", column=0)` and from `widget_ex.grid(pady=20,sticky="w", column=0)`, I get one pady value of 1 using:

```
widget_ex.update()
print(widget_ex.cget('pady'))
```

Any idea on how to call the one side pady/padx value?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In [a document of tkinter](https://effbot.org/tkinterbook/grid.htm#Tkinter.Grid.grid_info-method)

> grid_info()
>   Return a dictionary containing the current cell options for the cell used by this widget.
>   Returns:
>   A dictionary containing grid grid management options.

In the example of my code:

```
import tkinter as tk

root = tk.Tk()
a = tk.Button(root,text="getit")
a.grid(row=0,column=0,padx=10,pady=(10,20))
print(a.grid_info())

root.mainloop()
```

Result:

```
{'in': <tkinter.Tk object .>, 'column': 0, 'row': 0, 'columnspan': 1, 'rowspan': 1, 'ipadx': 0, 'ipady': 0, 'padx': 10, 'pady': (10, 20), 'sticky': ''} # It is a dict.
```

So if you want to get the `pady`,you should use:

```
widget.grid_info()['pady']
```